# Continuously sniff mails using Gmail API but without consuming large data

Tags: android, gmail-api

I want to sniff newly arrived mails every minute, I am currently doing it by using alarm manager. The problem in this method is that even if there are no new mails, I am consuming the network data. Is there a way that my app gets to know whether there are new mails without requesting?

Comment: Not sure how you are getting this data... You can get unread Gmail messages using the is:unread query string

Comment: @cricket_007 i am using is:unread query along with the required subject but for every request made to the Gmail API there is a consumption of about 1.5 kb of data every minute which is very high as it leads to a total consumption of 60 mb of network data even if there are no mails received

Comment: Have you looked into [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push?hl=en)? You can specify to only get a notification to your server when a new message with e.g. the INBOX-label arrives in your user's inbox. This will save your clients some data since they don't have to poll for messages.

Comment: @Tholle I don't have a server based app, is it possible to achieve it in a standalone  app

Comment: Push notifications is the way to do it. You will have to run a server that the Gmail API notifies of new mail and then use that server to send messages to the app using Google Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using Push, you could try to do polling using "[Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)" and restricting the reply to new messages only, by specifying a field selector: "history(id,messagesAdded),nextPageToken". That will return an empty return in case of no new messages and a list of message ids when there are new messages. Not sure how much data is required to do that however.